# jquery check if number is typed isNaN

Tags: javascript, jquery, focus, onblur

I have a quick form field where you can enter your age. When the user enters his/her age in words (like: twenty), it should give a quick alert telling that the age should be in numbers.

This is my code and it doesn't work

```
var formAge = $("<input class='inputClass' type='text' placeholder='bv.: 21'/>").appendTo(formDiv);    

$(formAge).blur(function(){
    if($(this).val() == isNaN){
        alert("insert a number");
    }
})
```

Comment: Replace your if condition with this condition if(isNaN($(this).value)){

Comment: You'd be better of with a simple regex.

Answer (score 3):

```
if(isNaN($(this).val())){
    alert("insert a number");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use javaScript **[isNaN()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_isnan.asp)** function.

Change your code like

```
if(isNaN($(this).val()))
{
        alert("insert a number");
}

var a = isNaN(123) + "<br>";
var b = isNaN(-1.23) + "<br>";
var c = isNaN(5-2) + "<br>";
var d = isNaN(0) + "<br>";
var e = isNaN("Hello") + "<br>";
var f = isNaN("2005/12/12") + "<br>";

var res = a + b + c + d + e + f;
```

**Output**

```
false
false
false
false
true
true
```

Comment: You're missing an important case: `isNan("2.365")  == true`

Comment: @JuanMendes that is still a number. and this will result in **false**.

Comment: @Jai I did mean to say `isNan("2.365") != true` which is not really a number, it's a string that can be converted to a number which is what you get back from a text field